# How to fix Laravel query builder where clause integer variable translated to string

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a function to get a pass a language number to get language categories record for API purpose. I use a database query statement to select categories table and join the category language table to get category id, parent_id and name (specified language). When execute return error and select the underlying SQL converted the language value to string (e.g. `languages_id` = `1`). I google a lot and no ideas what's wrong. Can anyone advise how to resolve. Thanks a lot.

I tried to copy the underlying SQL to MySQL Workbench and remove the `languages_id` = `1` --> `languages_id` = 1 can working properly. I guess the `1` caused error.

Code Sample:

```
private function getCategories($language) {
    $categories = DB::table('categories')
        ->select(DB::raw('categories.id, categories.parent_id, categories_translation.name'))
        ->join('categories_translation', function($join) use ($language) {
            $join->on('categories_translation.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id');
            $join->on('categories_translation.languages_id', '=', $language);
        })
        ->where([
            ['parent_id' ,'=', '0'],
            ['categories.id', '=', $id]
        ])
        ->get();
    return $categories;
}
```

Error return the converted SQL:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on
>   clause' (SQL: select categories.id, categories.parent_id,
>   categories_translation.name from `categories` inner join
>   `categories_translation` on `categories_translation`.`categories_id` =
>   `categories`.`id` and `categories_translation`.`languages_id` = `1`
>   where (`parent_id` = 0 and `categories`.`id` = 1))"

Comment: The error states the column name is the issue, not the integer - string conversion. Please do recheck the column names in your join clause.

Comment: which type has `categories_translation.languages_id` column?

Comment: categories_translation.languages_id is bigIntger, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `join` using a comparison to an scalar value, instead of a column. I think you actually want to put that comparison as a "where" condition, rather than a "join on"

```
->where([
     ['parent_id' ,'=', '0'],
     ['categories.id', '=', $id],
     ['categories_translation.languages_id', '=', $language]
])
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another thing i just discover with your code. when joining table, you are suppose to be joining 'categories_translation.languages_id' with another table id field. in your case, it is not so. you are not joining 'categories_translation.languages_id' with any table field. so ideally, what you are going to do is this

```
private function getCategories($language) {

  $categories = DB::table('categories')
                    ->select(DB::raw('categories.id, categories.parent_id, categories_translation.name'))
                    ->join('categories_translation', function($join) use ($language) {            
                    $join->on('categories_translation.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id');    
                    })
                   ->where([
                        ['parent_id' ,'=', '0'],
                        ['categories.id', '=', $id]
                        ['categories_translation.languages_id', '=', $language]
                    ])
                    ->get();
return $categories;

}
```

hope this helps